# Weird noise coming from laptop sounds static

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, fan

I've had this laptop for nearly 5 years and I've never noticed this noise before but due to there being an issue with the laptop recently I don't know if that is what has made me notice it.

The issue itself was that the laptop would randomly shut itself down or randomly restart itself when your half way through doing something this could occur after any amount of time, it then powers straight back up as soon as you press the button.  I've had it open and cleaned the whole fan and applied more thermal paste I've reset it back to factory settings but kept my data.

The static noise is there all the time it doesn't seem to dim.

[***This recording***](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeahtqeTrGo) isn't the only noise I am hearing; however if you listen to the computer in it, other than the noise of the fan, that is the same noise I am experiencing.

What could be causing this noise and/or random shutdown?

Comment: What brand and model laptop? Can you make a recording of your noise? Where in the laptop does it seem to be coming from? If you press hard with your finger in different areas of the case (underneath the laptop and around the keyboard), does the sound change or go away?